# python dictionary that requires basic dictionary format

Tags: python, dictionary, format

I am having difficulties trying to get my metadata to be in a certain format. I can't change the layout of the metadata i receive

```
metadata = [
            {"Key": "User", "Value": "3"},
            {"Key": "Customer", "Value": "3"},
      ]
```

what i want:

```
result= {"User":"3","Customer":"3"}
```

i tried:

```
def format_metadata(metadata):
   result={}

   for dictionary in metadata:
       result.update(dictionary)
   return result
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a quick dict comprehension.

```
metadata = [
    {"Key": "User", "Value": "3"},
    {"Key": "Customer", "Value": "3"}
]

result = {e['Key']: e['Value'] for e in metadata}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the desired keys to extract corresponding values from the dicts. For that you can use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(dict(map(itemgetter('Key', 'Value'), metadata)))
```

This outputs:

```
{'User': '3', 'Customer': '3'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by fixing a line in your code.

```py
def format_metadata(metadata):
    result = {}

    for dictionary in metadata:
        result[dictionary["Key"]] = dictionary["Value"]  # this line
    return result
```